I have a table with transaction details, I want to apply the amount of each payment to invoices on FIFO basis. any help is greatly appreciated
This is the sample Data, the value in Remaining Amount is the expected result



Posting Date
Transaction Type
Document No
Value
Remaining Amount




13-06-23
Invoice
2324PSI2802
176866.8
0


04-07-23
Invoice
2324PSI3778
79725
12297


19-07-23
Invoice
2324PSI4407
9835.8
9835.8


02-08-23
Payment
2324BR46
-80000
0


21-08-23
Invoice
2324PSI5206
611
611


28-08-23
Credit Memo
2324PSC02203
-44295
0


15-09-23
Payment
2324BR03956
-70000
0


21-09-23
Invoice
2324PSI5763
12563
12563


19-10-23
Invoice
2324PSI6090
7028
7028


18-11-23
Invoice
2324PSI6490
722
722


16-12-23
Payment
2324BR04870
-50000
0




How is remaining amount computed?

Remaining Amount is the amount that is left after subtracting the payment amount. Consider that the payment received is being applied to the invoices, to calculate how much amount is remaining to be received from the Invoice.                                                            Thank you for showing Intrest !

then it doesn't add up to me: if we sum rows 2 and 3 value column, we get 12,297+9,835.8 = 22,132.8. How is row 4, which is a payment of 80,000, putting the remaining amount to 0?

Row 4 is applied to the first invoice in row 1, row 2 and 3 are applied from payment in row 7

I have been able to able to achieve this result by splitting the dataset into two partitions, one for debit values and one for credit values.
